# Javascript screensaver animation not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

i just did a moving animation using left, right, top, bottom values. Like old windows screensaver. Doesn't exceeds the screen. Animate like a flow within the screenwidth. I have tried some logic. But its not working.

Using
    javascript

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
    console.log(circle);
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    var leftPos = 0;
    var topPos = 0;
    var rightPos = 0;
    var btmPos = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (w > leftPos && w > rightPos) {
            leftPos += 10;
            topPos += 5;
        }        
                else if(topPos==h){
                    topPos-=10;
                    btmPos +=10;
                }
                else if(btmPos < h)
                {
                    btmPos +=10;
                    topPos -=10;
                    leftPos -=10;
                }               
                else if (topPos < h) {
                leftPos -= 5;
                btmPos += 5;
                rightPos +=10;
                }
        else {
            leftPos -= 10;
            topPos -= 5;
        }

        circle.style.left = leftPos + "px";
        circle.style.top = topPos + "px";
        circle.style.right = rightPos + "px";
        circle.style.bottom = btmPos + "px";
    }, 100);
};
```

```css
body{
    background-color: gray;
}
p{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}
button{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p id="circle"></p
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code help you to implement logic

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var context;
var dx= 4;
var dy=4;
var y=150;
var x=10;
function draw(){
 context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
 context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
 context.beginPath();
 context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
 context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
 context.closePath();
 context.fill();
 if( x<0 || x>300)
 dx=-dx;
 if( y<0 || y>300)
  dy=-dy;
  x+=dx;
  y+=dy;
 }
setInterval(draw,10); 
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HTML5 Bouncing Ball</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body { background-color:#ededed; font:normal 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
h1 { display:block; width:600px; margin:20px auto; padding-bottom:20px; font:normal 24px/30px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color:#333; text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #ccc; border-bottom:1px solid #cbcbcb; }
#container { width:600px; margin:0 auto; }
#myCanvas { background:#fff; border:1px solid #cbcbcb; }
#nav { display:block; width:100%; text-align:center; }
#nav li { display:block; font-weight:bold; line-height:21px; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff; width:100px; height:21px; padding:5px; margin:0 10px; background:#e0e0e0; border:1px solid #ccc; -moz-border-radius:4px;-webkit-border-radius:4px; border-radius:4px; float:left; }
#nav li a { color:#000; display:block; text-decoration:none; width:100%; height:100%; }
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Bouncing a Ball Around with HTML5 and JavaScript</h1>
<div id="container">
 
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="http://sixrevisions.com/html/bouncing-a-ball-around-with-html5-and-javascript/">View Tutorial</a></li>
<li><a href="http://sixrevisions.com/html/bouncing-a-ball-around-with-html5-and-javascript/#comments">Post Comment</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bro using position only